# Undefined “___divmodsi4” linking Monotouch project with with wrapper for native library

Tags: xamarin.ios, linker-errors

I built a wrapper for twilio iOS library. I am using the following LinkWith

```
[assembly: LinkWith ("libTwilioClient.a", LinkTarget.ArmV6 | LinkTarget.ArmV7 | LinkTarget.Simulator, ForceLoad = true ,Frameworks="MediaPlayer SystemConfiguration AVFoundation")]
```

in Monotouch binding project.

When I created an iPad project that uses above wrapper library I am getting the following errors

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "___divmodsi4", referenced from:
      _jbuf_update in libTwilioClient.a(jbuf.o)
      _pjmedia_jbuf_get_frame2 in libTwilioClient.a(jbuf.o)
      _pjmedia_rtcp_rx_rtp2 in libTwilioClient.a(rtcp.o)
      _pjmedia_rtcp_rx_rtcp in libTwilioClient.a(rtcp.o)
      _rec_cb in libTwilioClient.a(audiotest.o)
      _play_cb in libTwilioClient.a(audiotest.o)
  "___udivmodsi4", referenced from:
      _update_filter in libTwilioClient.a(resample.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
```

At this point I don't know how to resolve that

Comment: Changing iOS target to 5.0 solves the problem. I am wondering whether someone could explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That function is a helper used by the compiler to implement a math operation that is more complex than a few CPU instructions.  Is it possible you build your library with one compiler and are now linking in a different environment and a different compiler?  If you built with `gcc` that function would be provided by `libgcc.a`.

Comment: Is there a solution for this, if you cannot recompile the library, and you cannot change the compiler you are using? I'm experiencing a similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18721140/link-error-adding-library-built-with-clang-to-ios-app-built-with-gcc